# NetBeans: create Entity from Database

Tags: netbeans, jboss

I need to reverse engineer my database tables into Entity to run a Java EE project on JBoss AS 7. So I've added into the Services the JBoss application server and added as well as resources a MySQL datasource. 
However, when I try to run the wizard **Create Entity from Database** I can see as only option the default ExampleDS Database. There is no other option to create a new DataSource or use the MySQL DataSource that I've installed on JBoss.
[image]

I wonder if it's a NetBeans bug, or I'm missing something. I'm using NetBeans 8.0.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue with the plugin that you are using for connecting to the application server. I remember I had this issue when I first tried to generate Entity classes from a Database using a Datasource on WildFly. Are you sure that the target application server is JBoss AS 7 and not WildFly ?
If so, try to connect the application to a JBoss AS 7 /EAP 6 instead and see if it works.

Hope it helps
Edit: I've included a [JBoss NetBeans](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/primefaces/build-a-java-ee-crud-application-from-a-database-table-using-netbeans-and-primefaces) tutorial which shows the steps for reverse engineering database tables into Entity classes (and then JSF pages).

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I had selected for my first attempts WildFly as application server. With JBoss AS 7 it works. In case I need to use WildFly as application server, I'll try to upgrade its plugin.